# How to avoid rospack error in an environment where ROS is not installed?

Tags: qt, deployment, ros

So I created an UI application using Qt for ROS. I want the UI to basically run in any environment (Linux, Windows. Android or iOS). I need to run the UI in systems that do not have ROS installed. So I developed an UI application using Qt Creator and deployed the application as AppImage. The idea is to have ros master run in a different system(master). The UI will be run in a different no-ROS system(slave).

The AppImage runs perfectly well in systems that have ROS installed. Whereas in no-ROS systems, I get the following error when I run the AppImage:-

```
[rospack] Error: package 'image_transport' not found [librospack]: error while executing command terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::ClassLoaderException' what(): Unable to find package: image_transport Aborted (core dumped)
```

The image_transport is just one of the ROS packages I am using. When deploying, the application automatically takes the libimage_transport.so as a shared library. But I get this rospack error when running the AppImage. I am assuming this to be a ROS related issue. How can I solve this without having to install ROS?

Answer (score 0):

I assume ROS looks at the default install location of the packages and cannot find the `image_transport` one, because you `libimagetransport.so` is not at this location. I do not know if you can run a ROS specific program without installing ROS.

Is image_transport the first of your dependencies? If yes maybe the others would throw the same exeception after the `image_transport`.

If no I would clarify where the other packages are linked and whats the difference.

Comment: image_transport is the first library I have used. I guess the other libraries would also throw the same error.